# Dart: list<Map> how to get elements form list of map

Tags: dart

*i have a list like this*

```
List data = [
  {'anjana', '5:30'},
  {'ram', '5:00'},
  {'Sruthi', '4:30'},
  {'devid', '2:30'}
];
```

And I want to get the item `anjana` how to get that value from this list ?

*And my second doubt is* with my this code:

```
UpdatesScrollData() async {
  SharedPreferences saveAllmedicineData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final alldata = saveAllmedicineData.getStringList("medicine");
  print(alldata);
}
```

I got output like:

```
[
  {'anjana', '5:30'},
  {'ram', '5:00'},
  {'Sruthi', '4:30'},
  {'devid', '2:30'}
]
```

So I want fetch the item anjana. how can i do that ?
when `alldata`  is `List<String>`

Comment: You output example is not `List<String>` but `List<Set<String>>`. Or is `"{'anjana', '5:30'}"` actually a String? How did you end up with data like this? It is not valid JSON so we need to parse it manually to convert it back to a `Set`.

Comment: @julemand101 how can i do that?

Comment: I can write a simple parser for you based on the syntax in your question. Give me a minute.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, please never write:

```
List data = [...];
```

This makes the `data` variable of the type `List<dynamic>` which removes all statically type safety. Instead, use the full correct type like:

```
List<Set<String>> data = [...];
```

Or use `var` or `final` to let Dart automatically determine the most precise type of the `data` variable.

Second, `Set` is really not something where you should select a specific element (the reason why it does not implement the `[]` operator) since some of the `Set` implementation can have a random order. But in this case you are using the default implementation where the order is the same as the elements was added.

If you want a specific element of a `Set` you can use the `elementAt` method like:

```
data[0].elementAt(0);
```

Or in this specific case use `first`:

```
data[0].first;
```

But if you want to access your data by index, you should really use a `List` instead of `Set`. Or in your example here, I would properly use a `Map<String, String>` instead since it looks like your data are related to each other in a key-value relationship:

```
final data = {
  'anjana': '5:30',
  'ram': '5:00',
  'Sruthi': '4:30',
  'devid': '2:30'
};
```

### Update for parsing the `List<String>` to `List<Set<String>>`

I have made the following example for parsing your input to `List<Set<String>>`:

```
void main() {
  final input = [
    "{'anjana', '5:30'}",
    "{'ram', '5:00'}",
    "{'Sruthi', '4:30'}",
    "{'devid', '2:30'}"
  ];

  final output = [...input.map(parseSetString)];
  print(output); // [{anjana, 5:30}, {ram, 5:00}, {Sruthi, 4:30}, {devid, 2:30}]
  print(output[0].first); // anjana
}

Set<String> parseSetString(String setString) => setString
    .substring(1, setString.length - 1)
    .split(', ')
    .map((part) => part.substring(1, part.length - 1))
    .toSet();
```

It is not perfect since it cannot handle if your substrings in your sets contains comma (`,`) since I use that for splitting each part.

Comment: how can i convert ```List<String>``` to ```List<set<String>>```

Comment: @engineerschoice Can you update your question with example of your input and expected output?

Comment: @engineerschoice Not sure how I should read that but if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted. If not, please give a comment about what the answer needs before it can be accepted. :)